# Stored procedure not returning affected rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is (exactly) one of my stored procedures. It does not return affected rows when it was executed. So I try to run this whole query providing the given values for the parameters and then it return one (1) affected row. I wonder why it does not return affected rows when it is inside a stored procedure. I also remove the SET NOCOUNT ON so that it will not prevent the extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements. Please help.

Here is the execute statement

```
exec STOREPROCEDURENAME @levelnumber=1,@laborlevelid=7,@laborlevelreferenceid=0
go
```

and the contents of the stored procedure

```
@levelnumber int = 0, 
@laborlevelid int = 0,
@laborlevelreferenceid int = 0

UPDATE LaborLevelReference SET
        LaborLevelID1 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 0 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID1 END),
        LaborLevelID2 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 1 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID2 END),
        LaborLevelID3 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 2 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID3 END),
        LaborLevelID4 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 3 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID4 END),
        LaborLevelID5 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 4 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID5 END),
        LaborLevelID6 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 5 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID6 END),
        LaborLevelID7 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 6 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID7 END),
        LaborLevelID8 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 7 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID8 END),
        LaborLevelID9 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 8 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID9 END),
        LaborLevelID10 = (CASE WHEN @levelnumber = 9 THEN @laborlevelid ELSE LaborLevelID10 END)
    WHERE LaborLevelReferenceID = @laborlevelreferenceid
```

Comment: only reason I could think of is having "SET NOCOUNT ON" somewhere in the SP or somewhere its being turned on in the session.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm sure that there are no "SET NOCOUNT ON" in any part of my stored procedure.

Comment: What you could do is use SET NOCOUNT OFF on the top of your stored procedure to override any other setting.

Comment: @SatheeshVariath I already done that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the effort trying to help me. But the problem is not in the query or the stored procedure itself. I found out that the ultimate error was my **STUPIDITY**. I am passing the wrong value to a parameter.

```
@levelnumber int = 0, 
@laborlevelid int = 0,
@laborlevelreferenceid int = 0
```

Here is the sql profiler execute statement that I was able to traced

```
exec STOREPROCEDURENAME @levelnumber=1,@laborlevelid=7,@laborlevelreferenceid=0
go
```

In my function in program, I've interchanged the `@levelnumber` and `@laborlevelreferenceid`
they should be like this

```
exec STOREPROCEDURENAME @levelnumber=0,@laborlevelid=7,@laborlevelreferenceid=1
go
```

The stored procedure will not return any affected rows because there are no `LaborLevelReferenceID` (It was my primary key and auto increment) which equals to `0`

**It was after all my fault. Thanks for the effort guys!**

Answer (score 1):

## Bulk Binds (BULK COLLECT & FORALL) and Record Processing in Oracle

Although this topic involves a much larger discussion of how to optimize database DML operations for large record sets, this approach is applicable for variable magnitudes of record volumes and even has a nice feature set, which includes a DML option called **SAVE EXCEPTIONS**, which enables a database operation to SKIP and continue past individual DML transactions that have encountered EXCEPTIONS.

I have adapted a script and added some additional explanatory notation to show how this works.  If you would like some additional reading from the source I used, see the following link for a discussion on [Oracle DML Bulk Binds and Record Processing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i.php#save_exceptions).

### The Sample Table:  exception_test

Use the DDL Below to create the test table used to store the data from our procedure's Bulk Binding DML commands:

```
CREATE TABLE  "EXCEPTION_TEST" 
   (     "ID" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EXCEPTION_TEST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
/
```

The Primary Key is the single column.  It has an assigned NOT NULL constraint which will be the property used later for generating several exceptions.

### Stored Procedure: proc_exam_save_exceptions

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc_exam_save_exceptions IS

-- Declare and Instantiate Data Types
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF exception_test%ROWTYPE;
  l_tab          t_tab := t_tab();
  l_error_count  NUMBER;

  ex_dml_errors EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_dml_errors, -24381);

BEGIN

  -- Fill the collection.
  FOR i IN 1 .. 2000 LOOP
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last).id := i;
  END LOOP;


  -- Cause a failure or two.
  l_tab(50).id   := NULL;
  l_tab(51).id   := NULL;
  l_tab(1250).id := NULL;
  l_tab(1252).id := NULL;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE exception_test';

  -- Perform a bulk operation.
  BEGIN
  
    FORALL i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT INTO exception_test
      VALUES l_tab(i);


  EXCEPTION
  
    WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
      l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
      
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
          ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
          ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
  
      END LOOP;
   END;
END;
```

​

The first loop instantiates a collection type variable (nested table) and initializes it with a non-null value.  Note the block of this procedure:

```
-- Cause a failure or two.
l_tab(50).id   := NULL;
l_tab(51).id   := NULL;
l_tab(1250).id := NULL;
l_tab(1252).id := NULL;
```

Which changes index positions 50, 51, 1250 and 1252 with a NULL value to force a DML error against the table constraint of the ID column on table *exception_test*.  Compiling this procedure and executing it from the command line reveals in the DBMS OUT display a feedback message identifying the DML operations that failed by an internal count of each loop iteration...

### Testing the Stored Procedure

Call the procedure to iterate through the defined DML loops and verify the BULK EXCEPTION HANDLING feature at work.

```
-- Command to Call Procedure

begin
   proc_exam_save_exceptions();
end;
```

The following is the output of this procedure's execution:

```
Number of failures: 4
Error: 1 Array Index: 50 Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()
Error: 2 Array Index: 51 Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()
Error: 3 Array Index: 1250 Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()
Error: 4 Array Index: 1252 Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()

Statement processed.

0.05 seconds
```

An additional query of the target table shows that DML errors introduced in the middle of the loop iterations did not interrupt the completion of the other loops and their assigned DML operation.

[image: Sample Verification of Skipped Exception Values]

### Additional Notes and Discussion

Here are some parting notes to keep in mind when using the **SAVE EXCEPTIONS** Bulk DML option:

1. The meta information in the *error_index* value of the resulting collection:   **SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS** is based on the count of loop iterations from the initial cursor query of the data.

   i.e., You will still need to correlate in some way that the error in loop iteration #51 (error_index = 51) lines up with whatever identifying key exists in your actual DML target tables.  I recommend at least using ORDER BY clauses carefully and consistently in your DML cursors so that your loop iterations are consistently matched with the same index/key values.
2. There are some additional extensions to the functionality of the SAVE EXCEPTIONS and BULK DML handling alternatives that may prove to serve additional utility above traditional approaches to large volume DML operations.  Among them includes:  error threshold limitations (i.e., quit when a pre-defined number of DML exceptions are handled) and Bulk Processing loop size definitions.

Comment: do you mean that my stored procedure is generating a sql exception?

Comment: Im using MS SQL Server, your script was based on an Oracle DB, should this thing works also on MS SQL Server?

Comment: Probably not.  My post is an Oracle specific solution... I am not sure if there is MSSQL equivallent to this functionality. The OP may have originally been mis-tagged with something that identified it as an Oracle DB problem... I have only been looking for Oracle questions lately, so this seems like a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: Though I have already an answer for my question. I thank you for giving me an idea about catching exceptions from sql query. +1